# Layer error: No valid training data were found

Tags: google-earth-engine, layers, classification, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, land-classification

I am creating soil land use classification through the use of [ee.Classifier.smileCart()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-classifier-smilecart).

I created the variable training, but I got an error:

> Layer error: No valid training data were found.

---

```
// This is the Sentinel-2 collection (all the possible available Sentinel 2 imagery)
var image = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
.filterDate('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31')
.filterBounds(geometry)
.filterMetadata('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', 'less_than', 30)
.median();

var visParamsTrue = {bands: ['B4','B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 3000};

Map.addLayer(image.clip(geometry), visParamsTrue, 'Sentinel 2');
Map.centerObject(geometry, 8);

var training = mata.merge(solo).merge(capoeira);
print(training);
var label = 'classe';
var bands = ['B2', 'B3', 'B4', 'B8'];
var input = image.select(bands);

var trainImage = input.sampleRegions({
  collection: training,
  properties: [label],
  scale: 10
});

var trainingData = trainImage.randomColumn();
var trainSet = trainingData.filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('randon', 0.5));
var testSet = trainingData.filter(ee.Filter.greaterThanOrEquals('random',0.5));


// classification Model 

var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileCart().train(trainSet, label, bands);

// classify the image
var classified = input.classify(classifier);

//Define color parameters

var landcoverPalette = [
  '969696', // solo (1)
  'ff8000', // capoeira (2)
  '006837', // mata (0) 
  ];
  
  Map.addLayer(classified.clip(geometry), {palette: landcoverPalette, min: 0, max: 2 }, 'Classification CART');
```

---

How can I fix this problem?

Code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/a3da0866ba122d4e4658a506f5bf4527

Comment: we cannot reproduce your error because you haven't shared your assets

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to contain the relevant block of code in the body of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a typo in the line that defines `var trainSet`. Probably that is why it is not working. The property should be 'random' in the following line instead of 'randon'.

```
var trainSet = trainingData.filter(ee.Filter.lessThan('random', 0.5));
```